# Passing a variable to a function using JQuery

Tags: jquery

the following does NOT work:

```
function doRestyle(div) {
        jQuery(div).css({
            "margin-top": addableMargin + "px",
            "margin-bottom": addableMargin + "px",
        });
}
```

However, this works:

```
function doRestyle(div) {
        jQuery('#idName').css({
            "margin-top": addableMargin + "px",
            "margin-bottom": addableMargin + "px",
        });
}
```

Any explanation? Many thanks :)

Comment: It should work if the `div` is e.g. `"#idName"`. Show how do you call `doRestyle` function.

Comment: Note that the trailing comma in your object literal will cause some older browsers to fail. Best to remove it.

Comment: @lonesomeday or most versions of IE (*shudder*)

Comment: What does `div` or `jQuery(div)` return in the console during the doRestlyle call?

Answer (score 3):

> *"Any explanation?"*

Apparently when you call your function the argument you pass in (that becomes `div`) is not a string with the appropriate selector or a reference to the DOM element in question (or a jQuery object containing a reference to that element).

You would need to call your function like this:

```
doRestyle("#idName");
```

Or with some variable that has been set appropriately:

```
var id = "idName";
doRestyle("#" + id);
```

Or perhaps in an event handler:

```
$("#idName").click(function() {
    doRestyle(this);
});
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doRestyle(someID) {
        jQuery('#'+someID).css({
            "margin-top": addableMargin + "px",
            "margin-bottom": addableMargin + "px",
        });
}
```

:D